# Undefined is not a function - Evaluating require.getModules() || React native || inline require || Enable Unbundling

Tags: react-native, require

I am trying to unbundle react native (inline require) and I want to investigate the loaded modules.

react native version - ^0.49.3

Followed official documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#investigating-the-loaded-modules

But it is throwing an error Undefined is not a function - Evaluating require.getModules()

Anyone tried it before or faced a similar issue?

Comment: Can you please provide some relevant code, it might be helpful to determine the cause of you problem.

Comment: @Dimitar

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#investigating-the-loaded-modules i am using the same code snippet provide here

Comment: Thanks. What is the output of `console.log(require);` ?

Comment: did you try on the release or dev version ? I had the same issue with my application bundled with `gradlew assembleRelease` but it worked in dev mode (with `react-native start`). `getModules()` is polyfilled by [metro](https://github.com/facebook/metro) and for some reason this polyfill is only applied in dev mode.

Answer (score -2):

just remove the code you added to create moduleNames for preloading in file

`index.js or index.ios.js|index.android.js`

and build again

Comment: He specifically mentioned he WANTS to run that piece of code. Removing it is not an option.